# Vue 2 & Nuxt 2 component is not rendered in production build

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, tiptap

We have a Vue 2 and Nuxt 2 component that is not always rendered in production, but is always rendered correctly in our dev build.

The production build command is: `rimraf .nuxt && nuxt build --dotenv .env` and the command that we use to run a local development build is: `nuxt --dotenv .env`.

Locally, our rendered page looks like this:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col flex-grow">
  <div data-v-5f7d20ae="" class="content p-0 outline-none flex-grow">
    <div contenteditable="false" translate="no" class="ProseMirror">
      <p style="margin-left: 0px!important;">...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, our production html sometimes looks like this:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col flex-grow">
  <commontiptaphtml content="<p>...</p>" class="flex-grow">
  </commontiptaphtml>
</div>
```

This `CommonTipTapHtml` component is used extensively throughout our application without any problem.

Initially, we thought that the rendering issue was appearing randomly, but we have found a reproducible way to make the bug appear. By following a set of `<NuxtLink>` the component will stop rendering correctly in most components that contains it. Then, if we refresh, it will render correctly again.

The culprit looks like this:

```js
<template>
    <div class="p-2 h-full">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center mb-4">
            <ResourceResourceContentTitle v-if="showTitle" :resource="resource" />

            <slot name="toolbar">
                <ResourceResourceToolbar :resource="resource" :hide-detail-button="!linkToResourcePage" class="grow" />
            </slot>
        </div>

        <div class="flex flex-row gap-5">
            <img
                class="object-scale-down object-left w-36 aspect-video"
                :src="thumbnailUrl"
                alt="Aperçu de l'image de la ressource" />

            <div class="flex flex-col flex-grow">
                <CommonTiptapHtml
                    v-if="resource.description"
                    class="flex-grow"
                    :class="{
                        'max-h-44 overflow-y-hidden overflow-ellipsis': collapsed,
                    }"
                    :content="resource.description" />

                <ResourceResourceContentRelations :resource="resource" />
                <ResourceResourceContentCataloguesLink :resource="resource" />

                <ResourceResourceContentKeywords :resource="resource" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <ResourceResourceContentMetadata v-if="!hideMetadata" :resource="resource" class="mt-2" />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        resource: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
        showTitle: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
        collapsed: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        linkToResourcePage: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
        hideMetadata: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },
    computed: {
        thumbnailUrl() {
            return this.resource.thumbnail
                ? `${process.env.SOME_BACKEND_URL}/not/disclosed/${this.resource.thumbnail.id}`
                : '/img/placeholder.png';
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

The `CommonTiptapHtml` element uses https://tiptap.dev and wraps it with our functionality:

```js
<template>
    <EditorContent class="content p-0 outline-none" :editor="editor" />
</template>
<script>
import { Editor, EditorContent } from '@tiptap/vue-2';
import Document from '@tiptap/extension-document';
import Paragraph from '@tiptap/extension-paragraph';
import Text from '@tiptap/extension-text';
import Blockquote from '@tiptap/extension-blockquote';
import CodeBlock from '@tiptap/extension-code-block';
import HardBreak from '@tiptap/extension-hard-break';
import HorizontalRule from '@tiptap/extension-horizontal-rule';
import OrderedList from '@tiptap/extension-ordered-list';
import BulletList from '@tiptap/extension-bullet-list';
import ListItem from '@tiptap/extension-list-item';
import Bold from '@tiptap/extension-bold';
import Code from '@tiptap/extension-code';
import Italic from '@tiptap/extension-italic';
import Strike from '@tiptap/extension-strike';
import Superscript from '@tiptap/extension-superscript';
import Underline from '@tiptap/extension-underline';
import History from '@tiptap/extension-history';
import Placeholder from '@tiptap/extension-placeholder';
import TextAlign from '@tiptap/extension-text-align';
import TextStyle from '@tiptap/extension-text-style';
import TableRow from '@tiptap/extension-table-row';
import TableHeader from '@tiptap/extension-table-header';
import Gapcursor from '@tiptap/extension-gapcursor';
import Color from '@tiptap/extension-color';

import BackgroundColor from './extension-background-color';
import Table from './extension-table';
import TableCell from './extension-table-cell';
import Image from './extension-image-mer';
import Rn from './extension-rn';
import Catalogue from './extension-catalogue';
import DocumentMer from './extension-document-mer';
import Math from './extension-math';
import FontSize from './extension-font-size';
import Figure from './extension-figure';
import Indent from './extension-indent';
import HeadingWithId from './extension-headings-id';
import CustomLink from './extension-link';

export default {
    components: {
        EditorContent,
    },
    props: {
        content: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
        useHeadings: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
        openRnInModal: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
        openCatalogueInModal: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
    },
    data() {
        const headings = this.useHeadings
            ? HeadingWithId.configure({ levels: [1, 2, 3] })
            : HeadingWithId.configure({ levels: [] });

        return {
            editor: new Editor({
                extensions: [
                    Document,
                    Paragraph,
                    Text,
                    TextStyle,
                    Color,
                    FontSize,
                    TextAlign.configure({
                        alignements: ['left', 'center', 'right', 'justify'],
                        types: ['heading', 'paragraph'],
                    }),
                    Blockquote,
                    BulletList,
                    CodeBlock,
                    HardBreak,
                    HorizontalRule,
                    ListItem,
                    OrderedList,
                    Bold,
                    Code,
                    Gapcursor,
                    Table.configure({
                        resizable: true,
                        allowTableNodeSelection: false,
                        editable: false,
                    }),
                    TableRow,
                    TableHeader,
                    TableCell,
                    Italic,
                    Strike,
                    Superscript,
                    Underline,
                    History,
                    Placeholder.configure({
                        emptyEditorClass: 'is-editor-empty',
                        emptyNodeClass: 'is-empty',
                        emptyNodeText: this.placeholder,
                        showOnlyWhenEditable: true,
                        showOnlyCurrent: true,
                    }),
                    // Custom
                    CustomLink,
                    headings,
                    BackgroundColor,
                    Image.configure({
                        HTMLAttributes: {
                            class: 'custom-image',
                        },
                    }),
                    Rn.configure({ openInModal: this.openRnInModal, editable: false }),
                    Catalogue.configure({ openInModal: this.openCatalogueInModal, editable: false }),
                    DocumentMer.configure({ editable: false }),
                    Figure,
                    Math.configure({ editable: false }),
                    Indent,
                ],
                content: '',
                editable: false,
            }),
        };
    },
    watch: {
        content() {
            if (this.editor.getHTML() !== this.content) {
                this.editor.commands.setContent(this.content);
            }
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.editor.commands.setContent(this.content);
        this.$emit('loaded');
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        this.editor.destroy();
    },
    methods: {
        /**
         * Returns the list of elements matching the given tag names
         * @param tagNames {string[]} - The list of tag names
         * @returns {Promise<[Element]>}
         */
        async getElements(tagNames) {
            let elements = [];

            // We want to be sure that the DOM is updated before getting the elements
            await this.$nextTick(() => {
                tagNames.forEach((tagName) => {
                    let localElements = this.$el?.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
                    for (let localElement of localElements) {
                        elements.push(localElement);
                    }
                });
            });

            return elements;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Finally, we use these versions:

- `"@tiptap/vue-2": "^2.0.0-beta.199"`
- `"nuxt": "^2.15.8"`
- `"node": ">= 14.17.3"`

We looked at other similar issues, but most of them were linked to tree-shaking, which we don't use.

Does anybody have an idea of what could be the problem and how we could fix it ?

Thanks for the time and effort!